# MediaPipe Selfie Segmentation results not working as good as the demo

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mediapipe

Hello I am basing myself on this demo
https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/segmentation/index.html?model=blazepose

It works perfectly when I move my hands and I am far way.

But when I tested it with the following script

```
const selfieSegmentation = new SelfieSegmentation({locateFile: (file) => {return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/${file}`;}});
    selfieSegmentation.setOptions({
      modelSelection: 1,
      effect: 'mask',
      selfieMode: true,
    });
    selfieSegmentation.onResults(onResults);

function onResults(results) {
      console.log(results);
      canvasCtx.save();
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);


      canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0,canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    
      canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
      //canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);


      canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
      canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      

    
      canvasCtx.restore();
    }
```

It doesnt work as good. When I move my hands around they become transparent not like the demo. How can I set the visualization settings that are on the demo such as
foregroundThreshold, Maskopacity and Maskblur?